# Unable to access my domain (BIND9 issue)

Tags: networking, bind

I successfully run BIND9 for using domain name over the local network (BIND9 installed in 192.168.0.74) but when I added WAN for adding the Internet to all the network, all the PCs became unable to see that domain name.

How can I fix this issue?

Here's my router configurations:

```
LAN IP:
IP address : 192.168.0.1
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
DHCP Server : ENABLED

DHCP Server:
Start IP : 192.168.0.100
End IP : 192.168.0.254
DNS1 address : 192.168.0.74
DNS2 address : 8.8.8.8

WAN:
Fixed IP Address :  192.168.0.2
Subnet Mask :  255.255.255.0
DNS address :  192.168.0.74
Default Gateway :  192.168.0.190
```

Here's my BIND9 configurations:

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
zone "my.lan" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/my.lan.zone";
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

/etc/bind/zones/my.lan.zone

```
$TTL 8640
my.lan. IN      SOA     ns1.my.lan. admin.my.lan. (
          2012121600 
          28800       
          3600        
          604800    
          38400 )    
my.lan. IN      NS      ns1.my.lan.
my.lan. IN      MX     10 mta.my.lan.

www           IN      A       192.168.0.74
mta              IN      A       192.168.0.74
ns1               IN       A        192.168.0.74
@       IN      A     192.168.0.74
```

/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa

```
$TTL 8640
@ IN SOA ns1.my.lan. admin.my.lan. (
                        2012121600; serial
                        28800; refresh, seconds
                        604800; retry, seconds
                        604800; expire, seconds
                        86400 ); minimum, seconds

                     IN  NS ns1.my.lan.

2                  IN      PTR    my.lan
```

**PS:**
When I use "nslookup my.lan" in 192.168.0.74 PC it works but it's not working in the other PC

ERROR message of nslookup

```
mbnoimi@mbnoimi-pc ~ $ nslookup my.lan
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find my.lan: NXDOMAIN
```

Answer (score 0):

is `mbnoimi-pc` running bind9? if its not try `nslookup my.lan 192.168.0.74` if that works you will need to update `/etc/resolv.conf` to use your bind9 server

Comment: is `mbnoimi-pc` the same box as `192.168.0.74`?

Comment: @max no... mbnoimi-pc is one of network PCs. BIND9 installed in 192.168.0.74 PC... the output of nslookup my.lan 192.168.0.74 is:   `mbnoimi@mbnoimi-pc ~ $ nslookup my.lan 192.168.0.74
Server:  192.168.0.74
Address: 192.168.0.74#53

Name: my.lan
Address: 192.168.0.74` the content of /etc/resolv.conf which exist in PC 192.168.0.74 `nameserver 192.168.0.74`

Comment: does that mean its working now? nslookup from `mbnoimi-pc` is replying with `Address: 192.168.0.74` which is correct? your orginal question shows nslookup trying to query localhost for dns instead of 192.168.0.74

Answer (score 0):

mbnoimi is trying to access a local nameserver at the loopback address 127.0.0.1. If (on mbnoimi) no local nameserver is running then /etc/resolv.conf contains the wrong information. If a local nameserver is running (on mbnoimi) then it is incorrectly configured.